# How do I write a simple if statement to check if the current user has already reviewed something?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, user-defined-functions

In the view I have tried everything. Currently I have:

### Leave a Review

```
  <% if current_user.reviews.include?(@book) %>
  <p>You've already reviewd this</p>
  <% else %>
    <div id="review-links">
      <%= link_to "write a review", new_book_review_path(@book.id) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :books, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reviews , dependent: :destroy
  enum access_level: [:author, :reviewer]

  has_and_belongs_to_many :claims, join_table: :books_users, association_foreign_key: :book_id, class_name: Book.to_s

def full_name
  first_name + " " + last_name
end

end

book.rb

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reviews
  has_and_belongs_to_many :genres, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :claims, join_table: :books_users, association_foreign_key: :user_id, class_name: User.to_s


end
```

review.rb

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "comment"
    t.integer "rating"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "book_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["book_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_book_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_user_id"
  end
```

nfortunately I still have the link showing to leave a review on the book's show page even though the reviewer has already written one for that book. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is a review? Where is that model?

Comment: I updated the question to include what you asked. Let me know if there's anything else I can do to make it more clear

Comment: `if current_user.reviews.where(book: @book).exists?`

Comment: @AbM yeah that's how you do it. Thanks. Forgot about exists. I'm such a newbie lol